# Using NSLingusiticTagger

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have put together a sample code to test the functionality of NSLinguisticTagger but had no luck. The code is as below. The problem is I never get in to the Block code which is a log.

```
NSString *linguisticTaggerTestString = @"My name is Jacob Thomas";
NSLinguisticTagger *lingusticTagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType"] options:NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames];
[lingusticTagger setString:linguisticTaggerTestString];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [linguisticTaggerTestString length]);

[lingusticTagger enumerateTagsInRange:range scheme:@"NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType" options:NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) 
{
    NSLog(@"Tag is %@ and the string is %@",tag, [linguisticTaggerTestString substringWithRange:tokenRange]);
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be the case that you haven't properly initialised the linguistic tagger.  `NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType` is a constant, you shouldn't be passing it in as a string.  try the following line of code instead:

```
NSLinguisticTagger *lingusticTagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType] options:NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames];
```